# Which Xcode build settings for iPhone app so it can run on ipad as well?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process

I have written an app intended for the iphone. Obviously it is ok if it used on the ipad in the iphone mode, but it is an iphone app.

My app got rejected by Apple, I received a mail with a screenshot named Screen_shot_0.png as attachment, that was empty with in the middle the text "My Universal App on iPad" (which you if you open in Xcode the file MainWindow_iPad.xib).

Probably the app was uploaded with the Universal setting, not sure.

I did add icons, launch images etc. for both iphone and ipad.

Now I am confused about the following settings (click on Xcode project file): I will give my settings:

Project "appname"

iOS Deployment Target: 6.1 (should I take an older one?)

Targeted Device Family: iPhone (should this be iPhone/iPad?)

Targets "appname"

Targeted Device Family: iPhone (should this be iPhone/iPad?)

Everything works on iPhone4, iPod, iPad3.

The only thing is that the launch image of the iPad is cut off a bit at the right side, which causes me to think that some iPhone splashscreen is used instead. Would this be an issue for Apple?

Comment: Why is the launch image truncated? Regardless of anything else, you probably want to address that.

Comment: is this an universal app as you have added ipad required resources??

Comment: I understand that 'universal app' means an app that runs on both iphone and ipad, but that they are custom designed for both platforms, in contrast to an iphone app, that will be displayed on an ipad in the same fashion. Again, I have an iphone app only and I understand from jbbenni that I should register it in Xcode as an iphone app, which disables any app icons and launch images upload facility for the ipad. The question remains, why is the launch image on the ipad truncated on the right side? Maybe I should remove the ipad specific images... I come back later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an app written for iPhone to run on iPad **in iPhone mode**, then you've actually done too much.

Just write it as a an iPhone-only app, and the iPad will automatically support it in iPhone mode.  iPhone mode on the iPad offers users a chance to zoom to 2x resolution, but everything is "as if" it's running on an iPhone.  *Be sure NOT to upload as (or set attributes to claim it is) Universal.  Don't provide multiple versions of screenshots, only provide iPhone screenshots.  Think of "iPhone mode" as an iPhone emulator that runs on the iPad.*

Only use "Universal" if you want to package both iPhone and iPad apps (typically with separate storyboards and definitely with distinct screenshots) in a single package that can run on either device.  Upload as iPhone only and it will run on iPad in iPhone mode.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I already suspected. I did remove all the images for the ipad, but that caused the app icon on the ipad to be distorted (probably took iphone launch image instead). So I added the app icons for the ipad (in the universal mode), put build in iphone mode again... and see... app icon for the ipad was ok as well as the launch image on the ipad. iPhone and iPod continued to function, so basically my problem is solved. Thanks!!